# Show Live Document Library by QueryString

Tags: document-library, caml-query, query

I am trying to build a page in which I can then add a Query String to pull the specific document library, showing all of the folder and files in it. Then from there I am going to create a webpart (using sharepoint developer) to show that library on another page that has multiple webparts.  I am running into problems figuring out how to use the page to create the query string needed.  Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box I don't think its possible. You can custom code a webpart which can read the library name from the `querystring` and display the result in a grid. But that will take good amount of coding effort.

The easiest approach is to edit the page, and add the library webparts. And then use JavaScript to read the `querystring` and display approrpiate list view webpart.

Comment: So if for instance I have 40 libraries with 40 url strings, I would use JavaScript to read the query string of one of the 40 webparts on that page and display the one needed? Is that what I'm reading here?

Comment: Also what would the querystring of the library be? I am for instance using Facility to create the 40 other pages.  This is hooked to a database.  If I can't chage the Facility number is there a way to make the library pull from this? 

Or could I add the document library url to the database and pull the library in from that in a webpart (i.e. Facility 40 is the url string, but it pulls the library attached to that facility id using the URL?)

Comment: Amal how would the javascript look.